# python read 16 bytes long double from binary file

Tags: python

I find python `struct.unpack()` is quite handy to read binary data generated by other programs.

**Question:** How to read **16-bytes long double** out of a binary file?

The following C code writes 1.01 three times to a binary file, using 4-byte float, 8-byte double and 16-byte long double respectively.

```
FILE* file     = fopen("test_bin.bin","wb");
float f        = 1.01;
double d       = 1.01;
long double ld = 1.01;
fwrite(&f, sizeof(f),1,file);
fwrite(&d, sizeof(d),1,file);
fwrite(&ld, sizeof(ld),1,file);                     
fclose(file);
```

In python, I can read the float and double with no problem.

```
file=open('test_bin.bin','rb')
struct.unpack('<fd',file.read(12)) # (1.0099999904632568, 1.01) as expected.
```

I do not find description of 16-byte long double in module `struct` [format character section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters).

Comment: ctypes supports long double

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python does not support binary128s natively, hence you won't find support for them in the standard library. You will need to use NumPy (specifically [`numpy.frombuffer()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html)) to convert from bytes to a binary128.

```
f128 = numpy.frombuffer(file.read(16), dtype=numpy.float128)
```